# Python threading leaving a thread unattended for seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I am trying to develop a stable structure where basically there are three threads running parallely:

1. One thread reading a serial port for incoming data.
2. Other thread checking continuously a file for new lines (basically same as previous thread)
3. The last one destinated to other periodicall functions calls like keep alive command through serial port and deleting old files.

First two threads are on a infinite while loop that always checks for incoming  new data, the third is a scheduled function that call other functions and sleeps untill the next function calls.

When my third thread is doing stuffs the other two threads are being delayed to handle new data. I have read a bit about GIL and maybe this is the reasson why I am having these delays.
Should I use other type of structure to priorize handling all the incoming data asap instead of the other thread?

Comment: You can use `multiprocessing`. CPython will not execute multiple threads at the same time due to GIL lock, but multiple processes are not affected. My suggestion would be to separate the 3rd thread as a separate process call, spawn it via `subprocess`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yesterday I tried to separate the 3rd thread as a subprocess like you suggested. After some adjusts the threads are working without delays but this give me other situation to solve. I am not able to have both porocess writing on the same log file and sometimes the subprocess need to handle the serial port that is already handled by the main process. I will continue looking for a solution for this issues.